# Android EditText text color auto changing during typing

Tags: android, android-layout

while typing into EditText, text color automatically changing from black to white, initially i set the text color to white and set hint color also white, but when testing it, it shows typing in black color on start but while in mid or reach to a random number of characters, it turns to white text. its working fine Samsung Galaxy Gio, Nexus One and on different emulators but on HTC Evo 3G and some other devices, its showing this behavior!
I tried to fix by setting style to normal, text color to white, hint color to white and other things relating to focus etc, everything is set to white but still on some devices it is showing the behavior and continues to changing color in mid of typing.
Please let me know if someone is familiar with this and fixed any issue like this.

Here is the video demonstrating the issue.
http://youtu.be/1dydBvZnSHI

Here is my xml for this EditText

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_edittext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:background="@drawable/share_email_bg"
                android:ems="10"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff" 
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
```

Comment: Sounds like there's some complicated interactions going on here.  What theme is your activity using?  Is it one that maybe those devices don't have?

Comment: First of all you are not typing into TextView it must be Edittext.

Comment: @Akki yes my mistake while typing, corrected

Comment: @ xbakesx I am using @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar
But if those device dont have that theme then while typing after some charachter it shows correct color so may be thats not issue but not sure about this.

Comment: @babur I am facing the same problem here. Can u say how u solved it? Thanks.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar as the client only having this issue on HTC EVO 3G and was working fine on all other devices so he deferred this issue. (means no luck :) )

Comment: @babur thanks for ur answer. By the way i have fixed this. I think you should also try this and check whether its working in ur case or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am answering this because some may get benefit out of this. Actually I got the same problem in one of my device and after a long struggle I found that its a very silly mistake.

To solve this we just need to add one attribute in the `<EditText>` node. Here is the solution :

```
<EditText
     android:textColor="@android:color/black"
     ..........
/>
```

Comment: as you can see that i have also used this like as under
android:textColor="#ffffff"
But in my case when we start typing it is in black color while i mentioned it to be in white color, and later it changes to white during typing

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/black"
```

in the textEdit if you refer to edit text down line change color when editing you need to set the color on:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
```